# slideToggle and toggleClass not working together?

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion, slidetoggle

I am trying to slideToggle and then afterwards toggleclass, but by adding the toggleclass the slideToggle does not 'slide' anyone know how i can fix this?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLk224xv/) and code below.

```
 $(function () {
        $(".expand").on("click", function () {
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('slidein');

            $expand = $(this).find(">:first-child");


            if ($expand.text() == "\u25B6") {
                $expand.text("\u25BC");


            } else {
                $expand.text("\u25B6");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: It is working perfectly, but you hide the element and THEN add the class.

Comment: maybe you want this: http://jsbin.com/pexabi/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working perfectly, but you hide the element and THEN add the class, so you can not see the `toggleClass`.

You made some mistakes in the CSS file and in the logic of JS.
remove the CSS3 transitions and it will works ok.

```
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
```

Finally, sort the code without the `toggle` methods, like this:

```
 $(function () {
    $(".expand").on("click", function () {

        if( $(this).parent().find('.detail').css('display') == 'block' ){ 
          $(this).parent().find('.detail').slideUp();
          $(this).parent().find('#titles').animate({'left' : -200});
        } else {
          $(this).parent().find('.detail').slideDown();
          $(this).parent().find('#titles').animate({'left' : 0});
        }

    });

});
```

See my working demo: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/pexabi/edit?html,css,js,console,output). Is it what you need to have?

Comment: i don't think you understand the question. Its still the same the 'slideToggle' as in when it slides up and down is still jumpy.

Comment: Now understand: i removed the transition: all 1s ease-in-out; and it slide correctly.

Comment: ah crap thats what i need but i'm guessing you can't have both?

Comment: i need the text to slide in from the left

Comment: Yes! if you are good with my answer mark it as one that resolve your issue.